# frontend login is not working properly in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I did login for frontend, I can get user identity when i login, but when i refresh the page identity completely lost, So can anyone please tell me what is issue for this ? I am not able to get identity , Can anyone please help me to solve out this issue, i am working on this issue since 2 days,

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        //echo Yii::$app->user->identity->username; die;
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
            //echo 'test';die;
        }

        //$model = new LoginForm();
        $model = new User();
        //if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        //if ($postData = Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            $userName = $_POST['User']['username'];
            $password = $_POST['User']['password'];
            $rememberMe = $_POST['User']['rememberMe'];


            User::loginForFront($userName,$rememberMe);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r(Yii::$app->user->identity);
            die;
        return $this->goHome();


        } 
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I am able to get identity when login, but when i refresh the page at a time identity also clear, What is the issue i can't figure out this,

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

When i refresh this login page still it consider it as a guest user

Comment: what is your session and user configurations in common/config/main.php and frontend/config/main.php ?

Comment: did you try with a different navigator ? maybe it is a cookies storing related issue.

Comment: I have experienced this kind of problems before. The issue was with the php configuration in my shared hosting provider. I solved it by using DbSession.